# is it possible to declare variable in a constructor in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

This is the component I am referring to its a child component to the main component 
when the app is run, an error is thrown pointing to this components selector `<app-new></app-new>`

error says:

> 'No provider for String! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for String!'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new',
  template: `<h2>SOme New Compnent which uses interpolation as well</h2>
  <h3>{{someProp}}</h3>`
})
export class CompyNewComponent implements OnInit {
  public prop2: string;
  public prop3: number;

  constructor(private someProp: string) {
    this.someProp = 'set throught the constuctor';
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log(this.someProp);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someMethod();
    console.log('this is inside the ngoninit life cylce hook');
  }

}
```

// App Modules File

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewComponent } from './new/new.component';
import { DirectDirective } from './direct.directive';
import { SomeComponent } from './compy/some.component';
import { CompyNewComponent } from './new compy/compy1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewComponent,
    DirectDirective,
    SomeComponent,
  CompyNewComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: there's a space in the folder name, thats why the space

Comment: It would seem to be the fact that you are injecting a `string` into the component via the constructor. What happens when you take that out?

Comment: when i remove the constructor the error goes away

Comment: isnt declaring variables outside the constructor and initialising is same as `constructor( private someProp: any){}` = `prop: string = 'somestring';`

Comment: whats the difference when we add a service and when we add a property. In both the instance we are doing the same thing arent we

Comment: I think that works okay in regular classes, but not in components, and maybe services with the `@Injectable` decorator. Angular is going to think you want something injected in there.

Comment: are you sure about that? can you cite some reference where this can be verified

Comment: You removing the code, and getting a better result, seems to prove it. I just don't declare class level private variables for the component in the constructor, I just add them above the constructor. I do add variables I want to have injected in the constructor, and that works.

Comment: yes it works but the reason given is the right one or not is what i want to know. but anyways I might have to search for some reference

Answer (score 0):

i think the error lies here -> `constructor(private someProp: string) {
    this.someProp = 'set throught the constuctor';
  }`

in angular inside a constructor you add services not properties like you do in react.

So remove the constructor and add

`this.prop1 = 'something1';
this.prop2 = 'something2';`

inside the `ngOnInit()`

EDIT: `import { CompyNewComponent } from './new compy/compy1.component';` there might be an error there too...better use `-` for example `new-compy`

Comment: but we can declare variables in constructor, right? like this `constructor(private someProp: string)` I have done it before, it had no error.

Comment: what is the reason you dont declare variables inside constructor in angular

Comment: what we add in the constructor are services (singletons)

Answer (score 0):

If you define a class with a constructor, you can declare variables in that constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public str: string, public value: number) {
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    ...
    public myMethod(): void {
        let obj = new MyClass("Hello World", 10);
        ....
    }
}
```

However, when you define a component or a service, the constructor is called by Angular, which expects parameters with injection metadata, as mentioned in this [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable) about dependency injection:

> When Angular creates a class whose constructor has parameters, it
>   looks for type and injection metadata about those parameters so that
>   it can inject the right service.
>
> If Angular can't find that parameter information, it throws an error.
>
> Angular can only find the parameter information if the class has a
>   decorator of some kind. While any decorator will do, the @Injectable()
>   decorator is the standard decorator for service classes.